# Total Variation Regularization for Tensors in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pytorch, tensor

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pQts.png)

Hi, I am trying to implement total variation function for tensor or in more accurate, multichannel images. I found that for above Total Variation (in picture), there is source code like this:

```py
def compute_total_variation_loss(img, weight):      
    tv_h = ((img[:,:,1:,:] - img[:,:,:-1,:]).pow(2)).sum()
    tv_w = ((img[:,:,:,1:] - img[:,:,:,:-1]).pow(2)).sum()    
    return weight * (tv_h + tv_w)
```

Since, I am very beginner in python I didn't understood how the indices are referred to i and j in image. I also want to add total variation for c (besides i and j) but I don't know which index refers to c.

Or to be more concise, how to write following equation in python:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zMVJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function assumes batched images. So `img` is a 4 dimensional tensor of dimensions `(B, C, H, W)` (`B` is the number of images in the batch, `C` the number of color channels, `H` the height and `W` the width).

So, `img[0, 1, 2, 3]` is the pixel `(2, 3)` of the second color (green in RGB) in the first image.

In Python (and Numpy and PyTorch), a **slice** of elements can be selected with the notation `i:j`, meaning that the elements `i, i + 1, i + 2, ..., j - 1` are selected. In your example, `:` means *all elements*, `1:` means *all elements but the first* and `:-1` means *all elements but the last* (negative indices retrieves the elements backward). Please refer to tutorials on "slicing in NumPy".

So `img[:,:,1:,:] - img[:,:,:-1,:]` is equivalent to the (batch of) images minus themselves shifted by one pixel vertically, or, in your notation `X(i + 1, j, k) - X(i, j, k)`. Then the tensor is squared (`.pow(2)`) and summed (`.sum()`). Note that the sum is also over the batch in this case, so you receive the total variation of the batch, not of each images.

Answer (score 0):

... starting from the pictured equation that's not total variation at all. None of this is total variation. You're missing a sqrt before accumulating along the batch dimension assuming you want an l2 metric on channels.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).